# HAproxy - multiple conditions in ACL

Tags: linux, redirect, load-balancing, haproxy

I'm try to take few redirect on HAproxy and all of them don't work on the same time.
So in my config

```
    bind *:443 ssl crt SOME CERT
    mode http
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto http
    option forwardfor
    option forwardfor header X-Real-IP
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    timeout client 300000
    acl route_1 hdr(host) -i some.example.com
    use_backend some_example1 if route_1
    acl route_2 hdr(host) -i some.example.com && path_beg /test
    use_backend some_example2 if route_2
    acl begins_with_test path_beg /test
    use_backend normal_test if use_backend
    default_backend regular_backend
```

I was try to change order ACL `route_1` and `route_2` but only first of them working. Domain without alias is ok and works fine. Split `route_2` to two ACL's and place it into `use_backend` not working as I wish

Answer (score 1):

Well the order counts.

```
# Because this acl matches will the second not be evaluated
acl route_1 hdr(host) -i some.example.com
use_backend some_example1 if route_1
acl route_2 hdr(host) -i some.example.com && path_beg /test
use_backend some_example2 if route_2
```

My suggestion is to rearrange the acls

```
bind *:443 ssl crt SOME CERT

  mode http
  timeout client 300000

  option forwardfor
  option forwardfor header X-Real-IP

  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto http
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }

  # && (AND) is implicit
  acl route_2 hdr(host) -i some.example.com path_beg /test
  use_backend some_example2 if route_2

  acl route_1 hdr(host) -i some.example.com
  use_backend some_example1 if route_1

  acl begins_with_test path_beg /test
  use_backend normal_test if use_backend

  default_backend regular_backend
```